# Devel::Cover not collecting any data after startup with mod_perl2

Tags: perl, code-coverage, apache2.2, mod-perl2, devel-cover

I want to check Selenium's coverage of my web app, which runs on mod_perl2 on CentOS 6.5.

So I installed Devel::Cover, put `use Devel::Cover;` in my httpd.conf's `<Perl>` section, and restarted Apache.  It immediately writes some coverage data from my custom ErrorLogging.pm module, but then if I hit any of the app's pages via a browser, nothing further happens.

I also tried changing this in `httpd.conf`:

```
StartServers       1
MinSpareServers    1
MaxSpareServers   1
```

...just to make sure it'd be collecting all data from the same process.  However, after restarting Apache and trying again, the result was the same.

UPDATE: I also tried launching `httpd` with `-D ONE_PROCESS` as mentioned in [this thread](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.qa/2007/06/msg8746.html), but the result was more or less the same, except that I had to Ctrl+C the service when done testing, because it takes over the terminal, and at that point it segfaulted.  But the coverage database in the end was virtually identical.

[The docs](http://search.cpan.org/~pjcj/Devel-Cover-1.08/lib/Devel/Cover.pm#Use_with_mod_perl) don't mention anything different that I can see.  How can I get Devel::Cover to record coverage data for code execution that happens in response to actual browser requests via mod_perl2?

Comment: Oddly, NYTProf works fine out of the box, and I read somewhere that usually they either both work fine or both fail miserably.

Comment: That they usually both fail or succeed: http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.qa/2013/02/msg13370.html